# Множественная фильтрация данных

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

Помогите пожалуйста сделать правильную множественную фильтрацию, должна быть возможность отфильровывать по городу, тегам, и по дистанции причем у каждой категории много итемов например:

Города: Москва, Питер, Киев, Варшава, Лондон

Теги: Марафон, Полумарафон, Эстафета

Дистанции: 7км, 22км, 100км, 42км

Отмечать для фильрации можно сколько угодно итемов

```js
var events [
{id: 0, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event1", city:"Москва", distances:"100км", tags:[{id: 0, name: Марафон},{id: 1, name: Полумарафон}]},
{id: 1, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event2", city:"Лондон", distances:"22км", tags:[{id: 0, name: Эстафета}]},
{id: 2, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event3", city:"Москва", distances:"42км", tags:[{id: 0, name: Марафон},{id: 1, name: Эстафета}]},
{id: 3, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event4", city:"Киев", distances:"100км", tags:[{id: 0, name: Марафон},{id: 1, name: Полумарафон},{id: 2, name: Эстафета}]},
{id: 4, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event5", city:"Варшава", distances:"42км", tags:[{id: 0, name: Марафон}]},
{id: 5, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event6", city:"Питер", distances:"22км", tags:[{id: 0, name: Эстафета},{id: 1, name: Полумарафон}]},
{id: 6, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event7", city:"Питер", distances:"7км", tags:[{id: 0, name: Полумарафон}]},
]
```

как лучше такое отфильровать если к примеру для фильрации выбрал Марафон,Эстафета, 42км,100км, ну можно разные варианты выбрать

я начинал делать так: создал 3 массива под категории фильтров при клике по итемам записывал в нужный массив потом прогоняю так:

```js
    const { filterCity } = this.state; // массив выбранных фильтров по городам
    const { eventById } = this.props.Events.eventsList.events; // все события
    const allEvents = (eventById === null ? [] : eventById); //проверка на наличие данных 
    const filtered = allEvents.filter((events) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
      for (let i = 0; i < filterCity.length; i++) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
        for (let j = 0; j < events.tags.length; j++) {
          if (filterCity.indexOf(events.tags[j].name) !== -1) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    });
```

пока только для фильтрации городов, но тут можно выбрать какие хочешь города в разном порядке и будет норм, но правильно ли я делаю, потому что хочу в эту фунцию также сразу добавить с другими категориями чтоб проверяло по всем, это получается еще пару внутренних циклов, может можно как-то лучше сделать или так норм подскажите пожалуйста

P.S. я тут использую реакт задачка чисто на js

Answer (score 1):

Заведите ассоциативный массив (карту) фильтров и сами фильтры отдельно.

Так вы сможете создавать бесконечное количество фильтров и включать/выключать их когда вам это понадобится, чисто, красиво и удобно.

Например:

```
// Карта фильтров
let filtersMap = new Map();

// Фильтр городов
let filterCity = e => {
  e.city ...
  return результат проверки e на города;
}
```

или так:

```
let filterCity = {
  key: "City",
  filter: e => {
    e.city ...
    return результат проверки e на города;
  }
}

let filterTag = {
  key: ...
  filter: ...
}

...
```

Можно сделать фабрику фильтров, чтобы иметь к ним доступ через один интерфейс, ну да ладно.

Тепер вы можете в карту добавлять/удалять фильтры:

```
// Где-то нажали на кнопочку добавить фильтр городов
filtersMap.set(city.key, city.filter);
...

// Где-то нажали на другую кнопочку
filtersMap.set(tag.key, tag.filter);
...

// Где-то нажали на кнопочку "отключить фильтр городов"
// Удаляем из фильтра города
filtersMap.delete(city.key);
```

Фильтруем:

```
allEvents.filter( e => {
    let res;
    filtersMap.forEach( filter => {
      res = filter(e);
    })
    return true/false потому-что res получился такой, или сякой в результате фильтрации
});
```